# Create a vector of ascending and alternating elements from two varying length and unique vectors

Tags: r

### Problem Explanation

Given two vectors of variable length, and no duplicates between or within the vectors, how can one efficiently combine the vectors in ascending and alternating order?

Here is an example:

```
a <- c(98, 101, 104, 136, 154, 193)
b <- c(31, 37, 41, 44, 48, 55, 80, 118, 179)
```

The expected output is

```
c(31, 98, 118, 136, 179, 193)
# b, a, b, a, b, a
```

You can see we start with 31 from `a`, the smallest between the vectors. 
This is followed by 98 from `b`. Then from `a`, the next number larger than 98 is 118. And so on, resulting in:

```
A = 98, 136, 193
B = 31, 118, 179
```

### My Attempt:

```
x <- c(min(a,b))
lastwas <- startedwithA <- ifelse(x %in% a, 1, 2)

for(i in 1:(length(a)+length(b))){
  if(lastwas == 2){
    x <- c(x, a[which(a > x[i])[1]])
    lastwas <- 1
  } else if(lastwas == 1){
    x <- c(x, b[which(b > x[i])[1]])
    lastwas <- 2
  } 
}
(x <- x[!is.na(x)]) 
# [1]  31  98 118 136 179 193

if(startedwithA == 1){
  evenodd <- c(T,F)
} else {
  evenodd <- c(F,T)
}
(A = x[evenodd]) 
# [1]  98 136 193
(B = x[!evenodd]) 
# [1]  31 118 179
```

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: What exactly does your expected output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `data.frame`, `order` and `diff` like this:

```
a = c(98, 101, 104, 136, 154, 193)
b = c(31, 37, 41, 44, 48, 55, 80, 118, 179)

# Create a data frame for each vector with a different number in column 'set'
dfa = data.frame(val = a, set = 1)
dfb = data.frame(val = b, set = 2)

# Bind both together and order them by val   
df = rbind(dfa,dfb)
df = df[order(df$val),]

# Only keep those that have a diff different to 0
keep = c(1, diff(df$set)) != 0

result = df[keep,]
```

Result:

```
   val set
7   31   2
1   98   1
14 118   2
4  136   1
15 179   2
6  193   1
```

Comment: I like it. Both answers rely on a combine with a key, sort, and then diff on the key.  clever

Answer (score 1):

You could set name prefixes according to vector,

```
v <- sort(c(setNames(a, paste0("a", a)), setNames(b, paste0("b", b))))
```

and use `diff` of factorized initial characters.

```
res <- v[!!c(1, diff(as.numeric(as.factor(substr(names(v), 1, 1)))))]
res
# b31  a98 b118 a136 b179 a193 
# 31   98  118  136  179  193
```

Then split into a data frame:

```
d <- as.data.frame(split(res, substr(names(res), 1, 1)))
d
#        a   b
# a98   98  31
# a136 136 118
# a193 193 179
```

***Data***

```
a <- c(98, 101, 104, 136, 154, 193)
b <- c(31, 37, 41, 44, 48, 55, 80, 118, 179)
```

Comment: Very interesting method! The data frame added feature won't work with variable length results but that's only a bonus you've thrown in.